# R: build separate models for each category

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

**Short version**: How to build separate models for each category (without splitting the data). (I am new to R)

**Long version:** consider the following synthetic data

```
housetype,ht1,ht2,age,price
O,0,1,1,1000
O,0,1,2,2000
O,0,1,3,3000
N,1,0,1,10000
N,1,0,2,20000
N,1,0,3,30000
```

We can model the above using two separate models

```
if(housetype=='o')
    price = 1000 * age
else
    price = 10000 * age
```

i.e. a separate model based on category type?

This is what I have tried

```
model=lm(price~housetype+age, data=datavar)
```

and

```
model=lm(price~ht1+ht2+age, data = datavar)
```

Both the above models (which is essentially the same) does not produce the result I seek.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `subset` is your friend: `lm(price~ht1+ht2+age, data=datavar, subset=(housetype=='O'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use interaction. Let `age` be a numeric variable and `housetype` be a factor variable, consider the following:

Same slope different intercept:

```
price ~ housetype + age
```

Same intercept different slope

```
price ~ housetype:age
```

Different intercept different slope

```
price ~ housetype * age
```