# How to make group_by and lm fast?

Tags: r, performance, regression, linear-regression, lm

This is a sample.

```
df <- tibble(
      subject = rep(letters[1:7], c(5, 6, 7, 5, 2, 5, 2)),
      day = c(3:7, 2:7, 1:7, 3:7, 6:7, 3:7, 6:7),
      x1 = runif(32), x2 = rpois(32, 3), x3 = rnorm(32), x4 = rnorm(32, 1, 5))

df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise(
    coef_x1 = lm(x1 ~ day)$coefficients[2],
    coef_x2 = lm(x2 ~ day)$coefficients[2],
    coef_x3 = lm(x3 ~ day)$coefficients[2],
    coef_x4 = lm(x4 ~ day)$coefficients[2])
```

This data is small, so performance is not problem.

But my data is so large, approximately 1,000,000 rows and 200,000 subjects, and this code is very slow.

I think the cause is not `lm`'s speed but a lot of **subject** and **subsetting**.

Comment: The fastest way would be to not using `lm` at all, and to implement it in Rcpp with a list of indices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In theory

Firstly, you can [fit a linear model with multiple LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39262534/4891738).

Secondly, explicit data splitting is not the only way (or a recommended way) for group-by regression. See [R regression analysis: analyzing data for a certain ethnicity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51407989/4891738) and [R: build separate models for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43189497/4891738). So build your model as `cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4) ~ day * subject` where `subject` is a factor variable.

Finally, since you have many factor levels and work with a large dataset, `lm` is infeasible. Consider using `speedglm::speedlm` with `sparse = TRUE`, or `MatrixModels::glm4` with `sparse = TRUE`.

---

#### In reality

Neither `speedlm` nor `glm4` is under active development. Their functionality is (in my view) primitive.

Neither `speedlm` nor `glm4` supports multiple LHS as `lm`. So you need do 4 separate models `x1 ~ day * subject` to `x4 ~ day * subject` instead.

These two packages have different logic behind `sparse = TRUE`.

- `speedlm` first constructs a dense design matrix using the standard `model.matrix.default`, then uses `is.sparse` to survey whether it is sparse or not. If TRUE, subsequent computations can use sparse methods.
- `glm4` uses `model.Matrix` to construct a design matrix, and a sparse one can be built directly.

So, it is not surprising that `speedlm` is as bad as `lm` in this sparsity issue, and `glm4` is the one we really want to use.

`glm4` does not have a full, useful set of generic functions for analyzing fitted models. You can extract coefficients, fitted values and residuals by `coef`, `fitted` and `residuals`, but have to compute all statistics (standard error, t-statistic, F-statistic, etc) all by yourself. This is not a big deal for people who know regression theory well, but it is still rather inconvenient.

`glm4` still expects you to use the best model formula so that the sparsest matrix can be constructed. The conventional `~ day * subject` is really not a good one. I should probably set up a Q & A on this issue later. Basically, if your formula has intercept and factors are contrasted, you loose sparsity. This is the one we should use: `~ 0 + subject + day:subject`.

---

#### A test with `glm4`

```
## use chinsoon12's data in his answer
set.seed(0L)
nSubj <- 200e3
nr <- 1e6
DF <- data.frame(subject = gl(nSubj, 5),
                 day = 3:7,
                 y1 = runif(nr), 
                 y2 = rpois(nr, 3), 
                 y3 = rnorm(nr), 
                 y4 = rnorm(nr, 1, 5))

library(MatrixModels)
fit <- glm4(y1 ~ 0 + subject + day:subject, data = DF, sparse = TRUE)
```

It takes about 6 ~ 7 seconds on my 1.1GHz Sandy Bridge laptop. Let's extract its coefficients:

```
b <- coef(fit)

head(b)
#  subject1   subject2   subject3   subject4   subject5   subject6 
# 0.4378952  0.3582956 -0.2597528  0.8141229  1.3337102 -0.2168463 

tail(b)
#subject199995:day subject199996:day subject199997:day subject199998:day 
#      -0.09916175       -0.15653402       -0.05435883       -0.02553316 
#subject199999:day subject200000:day 
#       0.02322640       -0.09451542
```

You can do `B <- matrix(b, ncol = 2)`, so that the 1st column is intercept and the 2nd is slope.

---

#### My thoughts: We probably need better packages for large regression

Using `glm4` here does not give attractive advantage over [chinsoon12's `data.table` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940464/4891738) since it also basically just tells you the regression coefficient. It is also a bit slower than `data.table` method, because it computes fitted values and residuals.

Analysis of simple regression does not require a proper model fitting routine. I have a few answers on how to do fancy stuff on this kind of regression, like [Fast pairwise simple linear regression between all variables in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51953709/4891738) where details on how to compute all statistics are also given. But as I wrote this answer, I was thinking about something in general regarding large regression problem. We might need better packages otherwise there is no end doing case-to-case coding.

---

#### In reply to OP

> `speedglm::speedlm(x1 ~ 0 + subject + day:subject, data = df, sparse = TRUE)` gives **Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb**

yeah, because it has a bad `sparse` logic.

> `MatrixModels::glm4(x1 ~ day * subject, data = df, sparse = TRUE)` gives Error in **Cholesky(crossprod(from), LDL = FALSE) : internal_chm_factor: Cholesky factorization failed**

This is because you have only one datum for some `subject`. You need at least two data to fit a line. Here is an example (in dense settings):

```
dat <- data.frame(t = c(1:5, 1:9, 1),
                  f = rep(gl(3,1,labels = letters[1:3]), c(5, 9, 1)),
                  y = rnorm(15))
```

Level "c" of `f` only has one datum / row.

```
X <- model.matrix(~ 0 + f + t:f, dat)
XtX <- crossprod(X)
chol(XtX)
#Error in chol.default(XtX) : 
#  the leading minor of order 6 is not positive definite
```

Cholesky factorization is unable to resolve rank-deficient model. If we use `lm`'s QR factorization, we will see an `NA` coefficient.

```
lm(y ~ 0 + f + t:f, dat)
#Coefficients:
#      fa        fb        fc      fa:t      fb:t      fc:t  
# 0.49893   0.52066  -1.90779  -0.09415  -0.03512        NA
```

We can only estimate an intercept for level "c", not a slope.

Note that if you use the `data.table` solution, you end up with `0 / 0` when computing slope of this level, and the final result is `NaN`.

---

#### Update: fast solution now available

Check out [Fast group-by simple linear regression and general paired simple linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51996021/4891738).

Comment: `speedglm::speedlm(x1 ~ day * subjectm, data = df,  sparse = TRUE)` gives `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5` `GbMatrixModels::glm4(x1 ~ day * subjectm, data = df,  sparse = TRUE)`  gives `Error in Cholesky(crossprod(from), LDL = FALSE) :  internal_chm_factor: Cholesky factorization failed`

Comment: It is very helpful answer!! My R skill can't handle Rcpp yet, but I could see new field which I have to study. I will study from now on.

Answer (score 4):

Since OP appears to be looking only for beta, here is an approach using `data.table` package to calculate only beta. See reference for the formula.

```
dt[, sumx := sum(day), by=.(subject)][,
    denom := sum(day^2) - sumx^2 / .N, by=.(subject)]

dt[, lapply(.SD, function(y) (sum(day*y) - (sumx[1L] * sum(y))/.N) / denom[1L]), 
    by=.(subject),
    .SDcols = paste0("y", 1:4)]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(0L)
nSubj <- 200e3
nr <- 1e6
dt <- data.table(
    subject = rep(1:nSubj, each=5),
    day = 3:7,
    y1 = runif(nr), 
    y2 = rpois(nr, 3), 
    y3 = rnorm(nr), 
    y4 = rnorm(nr, 1, 5))
dt2 <- copy(dt)
```

reference:
[Inference in Linear Regression](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/linregin.htm)

In terms of intellectual understanding of linear regression, Lee Zheyuan's solution is the best (+1)

---

add some timings:

```
 system.time({
      dt[, lapply(.SD, function(y) cov(x,y) / var(x) ), 
          by=.(subject), 
          .SDcols=paste0("y", 1:4)]
  })
   user  system elapsed 
  73.96    0.00   74.15 


  system.time({
      dt2[, sumx := sum(day), by=.(subject)][,
          denom := sum(day^2) - sumx^2 / .N, by=.(subject)]

      dt2[, lapply(.SD, function(y) (sum(day*y) - (sumx[1L] * sum(y))/.N) / denom[1L]), 
          by=.(subject),
          .SDcols = paste0("y", 1:4)]
  })
   user  system elapsed 
   2.14    0.00    2.14
```

Comment: @李哲源, I added some timings. It could technically even faster but I am not quite sure how to do it though (i.e. turning on GForce)

Comment: @李哲源, yeah I just saw it. its quite over my head. will need to learn everything abt linear regression properly. have both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953709/fast-pairwise-simple-linear-regression-between-all-variables-in-a-data-frame and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996021/fast-group-by-simple-linear-regression-and-general-paired-simple-linear-regressi opened but have not gone through them yet

Comment: @李哲源, can I contact you via email re something about regression?

Comment: @李哲源, when will you be graduating?